# django forms queryset doudt

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

when were i fetch a data from model it  displays the all data from table.

support : i have table xyz

```
class xyzform(forms.Form):
   test=xyz.objects.filter(m='name').vlaues('doj')
```

in html

```
{{form}}
```

it won't output nothing,only submit button is displayed

if i remove vlaues('doj'),it displays all the data .

1.My question is ,how to display only specific filed in the form ?

2.Another question how  to fetch remote.meta.get('remote_user') in to query set filter in the form ?

for example :

```
  name =remote.meta.get('remote_user') 
  test=xyz.objects.filter(m='name')
```

Please reply with few examples that will be easy for to understand...

Comment: Please post some actual working code. None of this makes any sense at all - you can't just randomly put queryset objects into a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the django forms docs from the beginning to understand how to use the forms framework.
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/

Following the examples will illustrate "how it works" (5 minutes).

Forms look more like this:

```
class XYZForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.CharField() 
    # forms only know how to display themselves with relevant 
    # forms.FOOField definitions.
```

As for passing request variables into the form, you'd have to override `__init__` so you can pass extra arguments into the form constructor from your view.

```
class XYZForm(forms.Form):
    field = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, remote_user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(XYZForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # do something with remote_user

# view
form = XYZForm(remote_user = remote.meta.get('remote_user'))
```